# Converter mp4 to GIF in .NET Core

Tags: c#

I need convert video mp4 to gif only in .NET Core 5, 6, 7.
i created in Net Framework it's worked but i need in .NET Core

Please help..

```
using NReco.VideoConverter;


var con = new FFMpegConverter();
            con.ConvertMedia(path, "D:\\Video.gif", Format.gif);
```

Comment: what was the error occured

Comment: This code work only in NET Framework... I want make like this in NET Core

Answer (score 0):

Seems this `NReco.VideoConverter` not fully compatible with the .Net core, instead of that try to use `Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU`

Comment: IS this help me ? This library can convert video to gif ?